# Trying to get property of non-object codeigniter view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried foreach data from controller to my view, but I get error `trying to get property of non-object` in my `foreach($menu_down as $menu_downs)`

**controller**

```
public function index() {
    $data['menu'] = $this->M_home->tampil_menu_utama();
    $data2 = array(); //initialize your variable with array; 

    foreach ($data['menu'] as $menus) {
        $idmenu = $menus->menuid;
        // echo $idmenu."<br>";
        // print_r($data['menu_down']); 
        $data2['menu_down'][] = $this->M_home->tampil_menu_down($idmenu);
        // print_r($data);
    }
    // print_r($data['menu_down']);
    $this->load->view('head', array_merge($data, $data2));
    $this->load->view('home');
    $this->load->view('foot');
}
```

**model**

```
function tampil_menu_down($idmenu){        
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT menuname FROM `menu_master` WHERE root='".$idmenu."'");        
    return $query->result();
}
```

**view**

```
<?php foreach($menu as $menus){ ?>

    <li class="treeview">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i>
        <span><?php echo $menus->menuname ?></span>
        <span class="pull-right-container"><i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="treeview-menu">

        <?php foreach($menu_down as $menu_downs){ //error ?>

          <li><a href="#"><?php echo $menu_downs->menuname ?></a></li>

        <?php } ?>

      </ul>
    </li>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: can you check if you are getting both arrays in `array_merge($data,$data2)`

Comment: i print $data2 and i get array

Comment: @FransChaniago Have you tried replacing **`$query->result();`** to **`$query->result_array();`** . _This returns the data in array form , since you're saving it in an array index._

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the **$menus** in view and check whether it is object or array. If it is an array then you can not access it like **$menus->menuname**

If possible please post the output here.

Comment: my error in $menu_down as $menu_downs, this result from $menu_downs Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [menuname] => BRAND ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [menuname] => BRANCH ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [menuname] => DIVISION ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [menuname] => UNIT OF MEASUREMENT ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [menuname] => COMPANY ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [menuname] => MENU ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [menuname] => IT SUPPORT ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [menuname] => BACKUP DATABASE ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [menuname] => TIME GENERATOR ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [menuname] => EMAIL LOG ) )

Comment: To downvoter: please be aware that under a certain point threshold users cannot post comments. +1 to level off.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use array merge this way as it has unintended effects.

Do this instead:

```
public function index() {
    $menu = $this->M_home->tampil_menu_utama();
    $data = array();
    foreach ($menu as $menus) {
        $data[] = $this->M_home->tampil_menu_down($menus->menuid);
    }
    $this->load->view('head', array('menu' => $menu, 'menu_down' => $data));
    $this->load->view('home');
    $this->load->view('foot');
}
```

If that fails try this:

```
    <?php foreach($menu_down as $k => $v){ //error ?>

      <li><a href="#"><?php echo $v->menuname ?></a></li>

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: in this line <li><a href="#"><?php echo $v->menuname ?></a></li>
not show value

Comment: `print_r($k);print_r($v);exit;` in place of `$v->menuname`. Also did you try the first method before trying the second?